# Pointers - Lot of confusion

Tags: pointers

I get very much confused when it comes to pointers. I want to know each and every concept about pointers in a simple language. I know pointer is a variable which holds the memory location of another variable. But these are some of the doubts which I get. Please help me out.

1. Why pointers were invented( I heard its main use is in dynamic memory allocation but please make me understand this. I am getting confused ).
2. What pointers have to do with stack and heap? ( I often read in books they use the word stack and heap ).
3. How pointers are implemented ( I want to know how pointers are implemented internally in any programming language. Does it require knowledge of compilers to understand this.
4. Why they use the indirection instead of directly using the value of variable itself ?
5. What are the ways to master the concept of pointers? How much practice is needed?

I am curious to know about these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Beginner's Guide to Pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Pointers) is a very good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Ask and you shall receive friend.

Source: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=cpp%20pointers&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cpp%20pointers%20and%20references&safe=active)

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/
- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html
- http://www.oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/ThinkCScpp/Volume/chap16.htm